# FullCalendar - Google Calendar Events + eventRender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

An existing site that now has version 3.9.0 (previously version 3.4.0) of FullCalendar installed that is used to display content from various Google calendars no longer displays the event pop-ups when an event is clicked on to display the full event description. Instead the following code is being ignored:

```
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        showEventInformation(calEvent);

        // Prevent redirect to Google Calendar
        return false;
        }
```

I was wondering if eventRender is able to display the event information? My search of the current FullCalendar Docs has not revealed any information that shows how this may be achieved, or whether or not this is even possible. I'm not sure how to integrate/utilise the only code I've found:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
  element.qtip({
  content: event.description
  });
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "code is being ignored"...what do you mean? AFAIK the eventClick callback has not been removed. Some sort of error, or what? Have you set a debug point in your browser to see if the eventClick callback is executed or not? If it does, what happens next, does it execute your showEventInformation function successfully, or is there an error in the console or something? If it doesn't trigger the callback at all, then what happens instead? The standard behaviour (without your code) is that the page navigates to that event on Google's main Calendar website.  In short, we need more info / context.

Comment: BTW the second snippet of code you've found works nicely if you integrate the qtip plugin - it's another 3rd party plugin, you can get it on any CDN, and it has a website with documentation etc.

Comment: ... I was not aware that the default behaviour on clicking a Google event takes the user to Google's site. That is actually what is happening. What I would like to happen is that the event details are shown as a pop-up without the user being redirected to the Google website. I'll try integrating the qtip plugin and let you know how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: That is the default behaviour because the event includes a "url" property - when clicked, the browser navigates to the URL defined for that event. That's standard for fullCalendar events generally, not just google-derived events. In theory the code you've got for eventClick should work I would have thought...unless there's a bug or a documented change of behaviour whereby returning false no longer cancels the default click. It occurs to me that another way you could potentially get round it is to handle the eventDataTransform callback and remove the "url" property from each event.

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance, ADyson. In the end I have managed to achieve what I was after using popper.js by adding the following code:

Comment: eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
        $el.popover({
          title: eventObj.title,
          content: eventObj.description,
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          container: 'body'
        });
      },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify and to avoid any confusion: the solution to rendering the pop-up tooltips was achieved for a **single** calendar using the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />

<link href='/css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='/css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

<script src='/js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/gcal.min.js'></script>

<style>

  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }

  #calendar a.fc-event {
    color: #fff; /* bootstrap default styles make it black. undo */
  }

</style>

<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script>

  $(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listYear'
      },

      displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view


      googleCalendarApiKey: 'MyAPIkey',
// Single Calendar
      events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'gCalID-1',
            color: 'green',   // an option!
            textColor: 'black', // an option!
            className: 'my-event-1
      },

      eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
        $el.popover({
          title: eventObj.title,
          content: eventObj.description,
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          container: 'body'
        });
      }

    });

  });

</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use popper.js as follows:

```
eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
    $el.popover({
      title: eventObj.title,
      content: eventObj.description,
      trigger: 'hover',
      placement: 'top',
      container: 'body'
    });
  },
```

Thanks again to ADyson for all the assistance.